# get HTML content from C code

Tags: html, c, get, java-native-interface

I implemented a Java code that can send a request to a remote website and retrieve data from it. But I want the same code in C, but I can't find so much help in the C library. Can any body give me any hints ?

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";

        try {
            url = new URL(urlToRead);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InetAddress thisIp = null;
        try {
            thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(getHTML("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip="
                + thisIp.getHostAddress()));
    }
```

Comment: Hint: you'll have to actually write some C.

Comment: What part are you having issues with converting? As Matt said, you're not really showing any effort in the port to C, and you haven't asked a specific question about it.

Comment: I can't find how to write an url and make a GET request to it

Comment: There isn't going to be a 1:1 on this. You have to do a lot of the work yourself so makesure you know what the function calls actually *do*

Comment: See [How can I retrieve content from a URL in C?](http://blog.nu42.com/2013/03/how-can-i-retrieve-content-from-url-in-c.html) for an example of how to use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not have any functionality to conveniently get a web site like the standard Java libraries.

You can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) which is a fairly convenient way of doing it or writing everything in sockets yourself in which case I'd say familiarise yourself with C network programming first: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html)