# How to open a file specified in the URL? in C

Tags: c

I have a simple C web server. i can connect to that web server by browsing in my web browser: `http://127.0.0.1:5001/`

What i want to be able to do is retrieve a file (locally) using GET.
so i want to be able to connect with `http://127.0.0.1:5001/local/file.txt`
and have the server send me the file.

I am having trouble understanding where i grab the the URL from within the C program? Once the socket is connected it reads into a buffer. to see what is being stored in the buffer i made it print out and got the following

```
GET /local/file.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:5001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

My question is, can i use the information that is allocated to the buffer as a way to recognise a `GET` command and open the file path that is located in that buffer? That is, search that buffer for the string `GET /filepath/`

I can't seem to find anything online to point me in the right direction.
I have read through [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4.pdf) which was helpful, but didn't answer my question.

What is the best practice to open a file from a URL? Using a standard C library and UNIX functions and "translating" sockets by hand without the use of such things as `libcurl` etc.... i don't want to use libcurl, probably something along the lines of `strstr` etc... find keyword and open filepath...??

can i use something like this? so pass buffer into it...

```
        if(strstr(buffer, "GET") != NULL) 
        {
            // Get address
            inf->addr = strdup(line+4);
```

except that this would output everything after GET to a structure pointer... is there a way to limit this? ie... stops after a space is recognised? so just before HTTP/1.1, i read that /0 is a terminating function... will `strstr()` stop after reaching a space?

Comment: The C standard library doesn't provide any networking facilities; you'll need to use either OS-specific APIs (in Windows, `WinInet`, for example), or cross-platform libraries like `cURL`.

Comment: I wrote about this in response to another [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549062/get-html-content-from-c-code): [How can I retrieve content from a URL in C?](http://www.nu42.com/2013/03/how-can-i-retrieve-content-from-url-in-c.html)

Comment: You need to write or use an [HTTP parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser).

Comment: @LewisFletch yes, you need the part after the `GET` on the first line. But keep in mind you might need to perform some decoding, because special characters like space are encoded. In your response you also need to include http headers, like `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`.

Comment: you need to send the "GET File_URL" to the server and to open it localy, you need to know where the file is stored localy (may depend on your browser)...

Comment: Thanks @Wimmel . I understand that i need to grab the part after GET ie. the file path. the problem is i'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do that? do i pipe my buffer into say... `strstr()` and define it to read from GET ->>>>> End of the file path?

Comment: @LewisFletch you are using terms in a confusing way that makes it difficult to read what you say, because we are wondering what you mean. You don't "pipe" buffers into functions, you "pass" them. You can't "define" a function that is already defined, to do something it isn't already defined to do. Look here for a set of functions available to you and what they do: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/ . If you think no combination of those is suitable, you can write your own. Better yet, use a parsing library as has been suggested. Here is one option https://github.com/joyent/http-parser

Comment: As for your question about whether `strstr` stops after reaching a space, read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/ . If it doesn't mention anything about spaces, then spaces don't get any special treatment. You may want to look up `sscanf` or write your own loops that treat special characters the way you want.

Comment: @antron okay thanks, i understand the functions... i just incorrectly use terminology, sorry about that. and i'd really prefer not to use a HTTP parser. rather read the file path from the header displayed above. thanks

Comment: @antron oh yep i've already read that page.

Comment: Take those pages, your understanding of C strings, the fact that the request headers form a C string (after all, you were able to print them out), the list of C string functions available to you, and try to make a parser out of all of that that can extract the part of the headers that you want. You can also loop through characters on your own and roll your own functions. We won't write the code for you. If you have a specific question that isn't answered in the documentation of either C string routines or HTTP, or elsewhere on SO, please do edit or ask again.

Comment: @antron thanks. will try and do what you've said, wasn't looking for code just the right way to go about it in terms of functions to use. still wrapping my head around a few things, but thanks